# Is this zip function tail recursive?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I implemented it using continuation. I think this is tail recursive but I'm told it's not. Why isn't it tail recursive?

```
let rec zip_tr fc sc l1 l2 = match l1, l2 with
  | [], [] -> sc []
  | [], _ -> fc (List.length l2)
  | _, [] -> fc (List.length l1)
  | h1::t1, h2::t2 -> 
    zip_tr fc (fun l -> sc ((h1, h2) :: l)) t1 t2
```

Isn't this tail recursive? Do the failure/success continuations have an effect effect on tail recursiveness?

Answer (score 1):

There's only one recursive call in your code, and it is in tail position. So I would say your function is tail recursive.

It does build up a fairly large computation in the `sc` argument. However, the call to `sc` is in tail position also. In my tests, the function works for very large lists without running out of stack space.

If I try your function on two copies of a very long list (100,000,000 elements), it terminates successfully (after quite a long time). This suggests to me that it really is tail recursive.

Here is the session with the long list:

```
# let rec zip_tr fc sc l1 l2 =  . . . ;;
val zip_tr :
  (int -> 'a) -> (('b * 'c) list -> 'a) -> 'b list ->
      'c list -> 'a = <fun>
# let rec mklong accum k =
      if k <= 0 then accum
      else mklong (k :: accum) (k - 1);;
val mklong : int list -> int -> int list = <fun>
# let long = mklong [] 100_000_000;;
val long : int list =
  [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; ...]
# let long_pairs =
    zip_tr (fun _ -> failwith "length mismatch")
           (fun x -> x) long long;;
val long_pairs : (int * int) list =
  [(1, 1); (2, 2); (3, 3); (4, 4); (5, 5); ...]
# List.length long_pairs;;
- : int = 100000000
```

If you change your code so that the call to `sc` is not a tail call:

```
zip_tr fc (fun l -> (h1, h2): sc l) t1 t2
```

It generates the result in reverse order, but it also fails for long lists:

```
# zip_tr (fun _ -> failwith "length mismatch")
         (fun x -> x) [1;2] [3;4];;
- : (int * int) list = [(2, 4); (1, 3)]

# zip_tr (fun _ -> failwith "length mismatch")
         (fun x -> x) long long;;
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

I'm don't know enough about OCaml code generation to explain this in detail, but it does suggest that your code really is tail recursive. However it's possible this depends on the implementation of closures. For a different implementation, perhaps the generated compuation for `sc` would consume a large amount of stack. Maybe this is what you're being told.

Comment: Can't you use the extension @tailcall to check ?

Comment: A closure is not allocated on the stack. It can be returned from a function or stored globally (escape it's scope) so it can't be on the stack in general even if it sometimes could. The one ocaml compiler there is never does use stack, always heap. And this will use a lot of heap.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tail-recursive function, you build something which is like a linked-list of continuations, by wrapping each `sc` inside another anonymous function; then, you call the resulting continuation.

Fortunately, your continuations are also tail-recursive, since the result of one call to `sc` directly gives the result of the anonymous closure. That explains why you don't have stack overflows when testing it.

The possible drawback of this function is that it allocates a lot of closures (but still with linear complexity) before starting to do any actual work, which is not what is usually done.

An advantage of this approach is that the success continuation is only called when both your lists are known to have the same size; more generally, compiling code  to continuations is something that is interesting to know when working with languages (so your effort is not wasted).

If the function is part of some course, you are probably expected to directly build the result list while traversing your input lists, in a tail-recursive way, without delaying the work in continuations.

Comment: The more conventional way would be to construct the list in reverse and pass it along as argument and reverse it at the end. A hackish way it to build the list with mutable records and in the end Obj.magic it to a list. Both have costs (mutability is expensive) and profiling has shown a mix of both (build chunks in reverse and glue them together with mutability) performs best.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow If you want, I can include your comment in the answer (with credit); by curiosity, do you have references to experiments or articles w.r.t. "mutability is expensive" or "profiling has shown"? thank you.

Comment: Comment is fine I think. People can give points on the comment if they find it useful. As for references you would have to search the ocaml mailinglist a few years back about discussions on iirc a tail recursive List.map in batteries or core. The reason why mutability is expensive is that writing to a mutable field has to tell the GC about it. For short lists (fits in caches) the GC calls are more expensive than building and reversing. Once you exceed caches the reverse becomes true.